# Selecting an element underneath dragged element in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to select the element that is underneath the dragged element, WHILE
dragging. Selection should be done using the mouse cursor, bounds checking on dragged object is not required, just the regular mouseover event.

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.active {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 32;

var circles = d3.range(2).map(function() {
  return {
    x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - radius * 2) + radius),
    y: Math.round(Math.random() * (height - radius * 2) + radius)
  };
});

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(d3.schemeCategory20);

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}

</script>
```

How to do it?

```
.on("mouseenter", function() {d3.select(this)... })
```

doesn't work since the object is underneath the dragged object, so onhover/onmouseenter/etc events don't activate, and I need them to activate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to calculate the distance between the centers of the circles:

```
function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
  d3.selectAll("circle").each (function(c) {
    if (c !== d) {
      var distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((d3.event.x - c.x), 2) + Math.pow((d3.event.y - c.y), 2) );
      if (distance < (radius * 2)) {
        d3.select(this).classed("intersecting", true);
      } else {
        d3.select(this).classed("intersecting", false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5n6xxhj6/1/

Comment: It works while there is a small number of elements on-screen. For more than 10 elements performance noticeably drops. Still, works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're looping over the circle elements while dragging so it doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 3):

You can get mouse events working on objects underneath the dragged object by simply setting its 'pointer-events' to 'none' on dragstart.

```
function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
  d3.select(this).attr('pointer-events', 'none');
}
```

Don't forget to remove it on dragend so that the object can be dragged again.

```
function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr('pointer-events', null)
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}
```

Here's @disperse's slightly modified fiddle to show it: https://jsfiddle.net/samuel365/10gLvxde/215/